# Module Views slideshow unable to uninstall

Tags: migrations

I am going to upgrade my Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

Before doing migration, I clear all optional module check boxes and remove unwanted modules in ***Home > Administrator > Site building > Modules > Uninstall*** (In Drupal 6)

The module below can't delete. While I press "uninstall", my site redirect to site.com/admin/build/modules/uninstall/confirm and it is blank page.

> *Name: **Views slideshow: DDblock Examples***
>
> *Description: Slideshow examples using image field. Installs content type, view and example content.*

Would skipping this step effect the migration?

Comment: You need to add what you are using to do the migration.

Comment: @Brady What are you mean adding what you are using? Are you mean Drupal 7 using the same module?

Comment: What are you using to perform the migration.

Comment: Manually upgrade from 6 to 7. Before upgrade to 7, I upgrade it to minor latest 6 version. I just upgrade to 6.37. Now remove unwanted module. @Brady.